# AngularJs ng-repeat : how to bind the values from <input> which was inside the ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
 //Adding New Check# and Check amount Text Boxes
         $scope.texs = [{id: 'tex', value: 'tex1'}];
         
         $scope.add = function() {
           var newItemNo = $scope.texs.length+1;
           $scope.texs.push({'id':'tex'+newItemNo});
         };
           
         //Removing Last Check# and Check amount Text Boxes
         $scope.remove = function() {
           var lastItem = $scope.texs.length-1;
            $scope.texs.splice(lastItem);
         };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-6">
         <div ng-repeat="tex in texs">
          <div class="form-group">
           <label>tex:</label>
           <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="tex.id" ng-model="tex.id" maxlength="6"></input>
           </div>
           <button ng-show="$last"
            ng-click="remove()">-</button>
          </div>
          
         </div>
         <button type="button"
          ng-click="add()">Add More</button>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
   <label>{{tex.id}}</label>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Above i mentioned my code. here If i did not use the `ng-repeat="tex in texs"`,the label `tex` and `texNo` is displaying the `value` once i entered the values in input. But If I did use the `ng-repeat="tex in texs"`, the `value` is not displayed. I know the code is wrong,but what i want is If i click Add More and entered the values of the second `tex` and `texNo`, I want to display the both of values of `tex` and `texNo` in the Label.

please suggest me with something.

Comment: `texNo` is undefined. did yout try a tex.texNo? And  pls add a controller code.

Comment: i didn't tried the tex.texNo. My controller code is inside the script which i mentioned above

Comment: You have a `tex` item inside your `ng-repeat` scope, so you can use any properties of it, for example `ng-model="text.texNo"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tex.id` contains a string `tex` whereas `ng-model` is expecting a number.

You can use dynamic keys and provide an initial value to it

Inside controller

```
 $scope.texs = [{'id1': 1}];

 $scope.add = function() {
   var newItemNo = $scope.texs.length+1;
   $scope.texs.push({['id'+newItemNo]:1});
 };
```

Inside HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="tex in texs">
              <div class="form-group">
               <label>tex:</label>
               <div class="col-md-5">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="{{'id'+($index+1)}}" ng-model="tex['id'+($index+1)]" maxlength="6" />
               </div>
               <button ng-show="$last"
                ng-click="remove()">-</button>
              </div>

             </div>
             <button type="button"
              ng-click="add()">Add More</button>
            </div>
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/4hfL2wxz/4/)**

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to use:

```
$scope.texs = [{id: 'tex', value: 'tex1'}];
```

And in HTML:

```
<div class="form-group"">
       <label>tex:</label>
       <div class="col-md-5">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="{{tex.id}}" ng-model="tex.id" maxlength="6"></input>
       </div>
       <button ng-show="$last"
        ng-click="remove()">-</button>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>tex No:</label>
       <div col-md-5">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="{{tex.value}}" ng-model="tex.value" maxlength="9"></input>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: hmm..Not Working Same Problem.. you can able to click n number of add more button,and the tex and texNo textboxes will displayed n times. the values which typed inside all the n textboxes has to be displayed in the label.

Comment: i just want to display all the n texbox values.if any other way is possible, its ok for me.

Comment: Ok, where you want to store textbox values? In controller, i see only the {id: 'tex'} value.

Comment: sorry..just remove the textNo text.. i also Updated my code in above question.. thank you so much for your effort.

Comment: You can't use ng-model="tex" for binding, because of "tex" is an object, you can only use ng-model="tex.id" or it doesn't work too?

Comment: Can you pls add a jsfiddle? I think it helps to solve the problem.